# Count Unique Visits to the Drupal Site

Tags: database

Is there any way I can count unique visits to my Drupal Site. I have a customized reporting module for the Drupal within which I want to put the unique visits to the site based on date.

I am using this query:-

```
SELECT
  n.title, n.nid, a.timestamp AS visited,
  COUNT(*) AS times
FROM
  {node_view_count} a, {node} n where a.nid = n.nid AND a.uid = :uid AND n.nid <> 2120 
GROUP BY
  n.title
ORDER BY
  times desc,
array(':uid'=>$_GET['uid'])) -> fetchAll();
```

Do you think there is any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Visitors module](http://drupal.org/project/visitors) to either use it or help you with your code. It provides many features concerning visitors info and among them is the "unique visitor" feature you are interested in. A similar approach would be also the [Counter module](http://drupal.org/project/counter).

Comment: Thank you. If it could allow it, then that would be awesome But it only show it in block, Is there a way I can access the Query which Shows Unique Visitors based on their IP?